# Как сохранить массив элементов и затем работать с ним jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть несколько span элементов такого вида:

```
<span class=\"price\" data-price=\"$price\">$price грн.</span>
```

PHP скрипт их может сгенерировать достаточно много, в зависимости от ситуации..

Потом с помощью jQuery считываю значение переменной $price:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // Скрипт считывает цену товара и считает сумму средствами JavaScript
      var price = $('span.price').data('price');
      console.log($('span.price').data('price'));
      });
    });
```

Но так я вижу только стоимость в первом span элементе, как сохранить массив всех значений в переменную var price с помощью jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var price=[];
$('.price').each(function(){
    price.push($(this).data('price'));
})
```

И несколько советов:

1. Вместо `$(document).ready(function(){...})` можно использовать `$(function(){...})` — так красивее и меньше писать.
2. При поиске элементов с определённым классом не стоит привязываться к самому элементу, тоесть вместо `$('span.price')` лучше использовать просто `$('.price')`.

Comment: во второй строке выдает ошибку Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Браузер Хром.

Comment: @eprivalov1, простите, поспешил и упустил точку. Проверьте ещё раз

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо за помощь!